# Running 4" PVC pipe through foundation wall

Tags: concrete, radon

I am installing a radon mitigation system and my plan is to go off of the sump pump (I bought one of those covers that seals it up good and lets you pass a PVC pipe though it).

The easiest thing to do to connect to the fan outside is to simply drill through the concrete wall above the sump and go outside.  I have never done this kind of thing before and I want to make sure I am not structurally compromising that part of the wall by drilling a big ass hole though it.

Any thoughts/tips would be more than welcomed!

Comment: Not sure what would be structurally sound for your foundation walls without more detail, but from the pipe's perspective, you will need to have a strain relief where it passes through a structural wall--usually a pipe 2 sizes up that you sleeve around the outside of the pipe of the size you actually need.

Comment: For an radon  mitigation system it is far more common for the pipe from the sump pump area to go straight up to the area of the joists at the basement ceiling and then exit out through the skirt joist to the outside of the dwelling.

Comment: Michael Karas, why is that? any particular reason?

Comment: Going up and then through the skirt or rim is much less work. A hole hog with the correct size hole saw can cut this hole in a minute or two. Drilling that large of a hole in a foundation wall probably will not compromise the foundation but drilling through 6, 8 or 10" of concrete requires a core saw for a clean hole or a but load of small holes in a circle to bust out the hole that will be time consuming and more expensive. If you do go up and through the skirt or rim, using a large hole saw requires a powerful drill like a hole hog, use caution not to hit nails as broken fingers can happen.

Comment: I wanted to make this as reversible as possible so future buyers cant take issue with a hole in the wall or sill.  So I replaced a basement window pane with Lexan or Plexi and ran it through that.